# Help with fingering

Tags: piano, fingering

I need help figuring out fingering for the three notes from the treble clef captioned 1 2 3. I found two ways of playing that part, but both of them are very awkward and one even gives pain. [image]

Comment: Tell us what *doesn't* work for you, and we might be able to improve it - or maybe see that the problem isn't really about fingering but something else, like your hand position....

Comment: How big are your hands? For example, do you barely span a sixth with your right hand, or can you span a seventh or octave?

Comment: I can span 10th without any prior training. They are quite big.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you'd probably end up playing the previous chord [135], I think [14] 2 [135] is the most natural fingering.

Comment: Agreed - this is not the place to follow the "don't put your thumb on a black key" rule!

Comment: That's what I came up with, and that feels the most awkward, as my hand is bent to the right too much. The other one is [15] 3 [245], and seems to be more smooth.

Comment: That seems weird to me. Ending on [245] would certainly leave your hand pointing to the *left* and your elbow sticking out to the right, but [135] should leave your hand and arm almost straight. Get the 3 right up on  top of the black key and keep the 5 well bent on the G so it doesn't get tangled up between the black keys. Your thumb should be pointing forwards and nearly straight and horizontal, not bent and pointing downwards. It's possible that if you are self-taught, your basic hand position has always been wrong, but you are only just beginning to discover the problems that causes.

Comment: user19146 - there's no such thing as a "no thumb on black key" rule. Granted, you wouldn't do that much in a fast scale passage, but when chords are concerned it's just silly. I agree that ending on [245] feels odd, but what's the next note? if it's an a below the B flat, fingering the B flat with 2 might be best. it depends on the shape of your hand.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to play this melody, I'd be playing the low 'g' with my first finger (thumb) and the 'e' with my fourth finger (ring finger), followed by the 'c' with my second finger (pointing finger) and concluding with the 'b-flat' with my first finger (thumb), the 'e-flat' with my second finger (pointing finger) and the 'g' with my fourth finger (ring finger). If the last chord would be shorter, I'd consider playing the 'g' with my fifth finger (pinky), if the notes after are below that 'g'.

It may not be the "natural" way to play it, as some would say, but this is how it feels right to me. My view on finger positions is totally different; just try out different fingerings and see which one feels best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ultimate legato, finger the C broken triac 1,2,4 then just move your hand up to 1,3,5 on the Eb triad.   But what comes before affects your decision too.

I'm more worried about your statement "one even gives pain".   This shouldn't be even possible, even with the most inelegant fingering!  Consult your teacher or an experienced player immediately to find out what horrible thing you are doing.

Comment: I actually just started learning with a teacher, we do some basic songs. In the mean time, I like to tackle on advanced pieces. I'm pretty sure I do something wrong, but it's a week until the next lesson when I can consult.